# HorizontalScrollView smoothScrolTo doesn't work

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, smooth-scrolling

I have extended the `HorizontalScrollView` class to implement a certain behavior. Under the LinearLayout inside my `CustomHorizontalScrollView` I have only 2 child views (lets say `ImageView`). When the user scrolls more than 50% to one direction, i want my `CustomHorizontalScrollView` to auto-scroll to the end of the same direction. This is how I implemented it: 
`CustomHorizontalScrollView` class:

```
    public class CustomHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

    private static float downCoordinates = -1;
    private static float upCoordinates = -1;
    private static int currentPosition = 0;

    public CustomHorizontalScrollView(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx);
    }

    public CustomHorizontalScrollView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(ctx, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && downCoordinates == -1) {
            downCoordinates = ev.getX();
        }
        else if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && upCoordinates == -1) {
            upCoordinates = ev.getX();
            int scrollViewWidth = this.getMeasuredWidth();
            double dist = downCoordinates - upCoordinates; 
            if (Math.abs(dist) > scrollViewWidth / 2) {
                //this.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
                // Going forwards
                if (dist > 0) {
                    int max = ((LinearLayout)this.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(1).getMeasuredWidth();
                    currentPosition = max;
                    this.scrollTo(max, 0);
                }
                // Going backwards
                else {
                    currentPosition = 0;
                    this.scrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
            // reseting the saved Coordinates
            downCoordinates = -1;
            upCoordinates = -1;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

Up until here - everything works. The thing is that I want the auto-scrolling to be done smoothly so i tried using the `smoothScrollTo` function instead of the `scrollTo` function but then, nothing happens (as in no auto-scrolling). i tried declaring this:

```
this.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
```

but also with no success.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
    this.post(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
             this.smoothScrollTo(0, this.getBottom());
        } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This still doesn't work for me, so i find out that i need to after this line

```
this.smoothScrollTo(0, this.getBottom());
```

add this

```
this.invalidate();
```